# Joi Validation Regex or pattern

Tags: arrays, node.js, reactjs, validation, joi

I want to joi use regex pattern which define in variable

I have a variable **pattern** which contains regex
i.e

```
pattern = "/^[0-9+]{7}-[0-9+]{1}$/"
```

and this pattern send to Joi module and want to confirm

```
module.exports = {
    save: {
        body: {
          match: Joi.string().regex(pattern).required
        }
     }
 }
```

I know validation work if I use this

```
module.exports = {
        save: {
            body: {
              match: Joi.string().regex(/^[0-9+]{7}-[0-9+]{1}$/).required
            }
         }
     }
```

But in my case every time regex will different. So I can not use above regex pattern

Comment: Yes I want to use pattern variable

Comment: I have changed last sentence please check again

Answer (score 12):

If you want to use pattern as variable, just pass it:

```
module.exports = (pattern) => ({
  save: {
    body: {
      match: Joi.string().regex(pattern).required
    }
  }
});
```

And use it like:

```
const pattern = "/^[0-9+]{7}-[0-9+]{1}$/";
validator(pattern)
```

Answer (score 7):

```
module.exports = (exp) => ({
   save: {
       body: {
         match: Joi.string().pattern(new RegExp(exp)).required()
       }
   }
});
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should also explain **what** the code does and **how** it helps.